# There was no endpoint listening

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

When I try to call the method in the WCF host I get this error:

> There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse
>   that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
>   details.

I have a class that starts the WCF host:

```
public class ProcessUnderMouseServer
{
    public ProcessUnderMouseServer()
    {
        using (host = new ServiceHost(
            typeof(PrcoessUnderMouse),
            new Uri[]
            {
                new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")
            }))
        {  
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(
                    typeof(IPrcoessUnderMouse),
                    new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                    "PipeReverse");

                host.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

this class is in a different library project than the consuming project

Then I try to consume it like this:

```
ProcessUnderMouseServer ProcessUnderMouseServer = new ProcessUnderMouseServer();

ChannelFactory<IPrcoessUnderMouse> pipeFactory =
        new ChannelFactory<IPrcoessUnderMouse>(
          new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
          new EndpointAddress(
            "net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse"));

            IPrcoessUnderMouse pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
            string str = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("pipe: " + pipeProxy.GetProcessUnderMouse());
```

Shouldn't

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPrcoessUnderMouse),new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "PipeReverse");
```

be sufficient to add the end point? why it says that `no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse` ??

Comment: Did you try to give the full URI `net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse` as address in AddServiceEndpoint?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, it didn't work though :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247185/there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-net-pipe-localhost?rq=1